# Adding subviews to UITableViewCell in iOS5

Tags: ios5, uitableview

In iOS5 cell is allocated automatically, so there is a problem with adding subview to it,
because each time cell reloads subview adds to it.

What I do now is checking for subview and removing it before adding new, like that:

```
for (UIView *subview in cell.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:MarqueeLabel.class]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];

    }
}
```

does anyone have better solution?

Answer (score 0):

in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: delegate protocol method that you should have and definitely have implemented, try this:

```
      if (cell) {
   // This if statement is declaring that the cell is non-zero and valid. All your activity with the cell should be done here, add the following:
cell.imageView.image = nil;
// or
cell.imageView = nil;
// or most likely in your case
cell.subviews = nil;
// Then assign your subviews/image or whatever. This way it refreshes each time.
```

Also, are you dequeueing the tableViewCells like the following:

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:@"cell"]
            autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Cell is always not nil in iOS5.
cell.subviews = nil is impossible.